# holomorphic extension of a function

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, fa.functional-analysis

hi,

I have the following question: let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be some open set containing zero. let $\tilde{U} = U \cap \mathbb{R}^{n}$. assume we have a real-valued analytic function $f : \tilde{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Can this function be holomorphically extended to $U$ (maybe if we shrink $U$) in a unique way? I would be very thankful for answers.

bruno

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course, after we shrink $U$. A convergent Taylor series at a real point converges in some complex
neighborhood of this point.

Added reply to your comment: you can apply identity theorem. Two real analytic functions
coinciding on an open set of $R^n$ coincide in a complex neighborhood of this set.

Comment: but how can one apply the identity theorem in tis case (in oreder to get uniqueness)?